# How to un-subdivide whilst remaining the topology(Also not lowering the vert count below (8)k or max 10k)

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]How to unsubdivide/lower vert counts whilst remaining the topology, The quad remesh just stright up ruins my mesh, voxel doesn't work, literally just deletes my mesh, decimate, Well.. You get the picture.

here's the image for the wireframe.[image]

Mesh after quad remesh.[image]

Comment: Hello, what does Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide give? Also maybe show a screenshot of your wireframe

Comment: @moonboots wire frame added. the unsubdivide lowers the tris to 4k verts I'm trying to preserve as much as possible without exceeding 10k verts, un-sub (two step) cause the verts to go around 4.8k.

Comment: You say that you want to be between 4k and 10k, so what's the problem with unsubdivide? Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Oh, I noticed, I mean 8k verts to 10 k verts. I'm sorry :/ .

Comment: If unsubdivide and remesh don't work I'm not sure there's any other automatic method, if you want to keep quads of course. But you can do it manually with the checker deselect method

Comment: Oh god, The suffering.

Comment: Is there any reason why quad remesh doesn't work? Or is it another topic.

Comment: You have some apps that can remesh, like Instant Remesh, they may give a better result than the Remesh tool of Blender, but it's not magical either. Retopologize with the checker deselect is not so complicated.

Comment: Got it, Imma learn it then. Thanks for the advice :D

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? It probably doesn't give the result you want, but an algorithm can't guess how to do a good topology

Comment: if you want me to explain checker deselect, please ask

Comment: I can show you the mesh after quad, And also thanks but unless you have time, I can just learn it by my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the automatic tools like *Remesh* don't correctly reduce the topology, do it manually with the *Checker Deselect* method:

- Select a ring of edges (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> right click):

[image]

- Go into *Select > Checker Deselect* and the *Operator* box choose the selection ratio (by default it will keep selected one edge out of two, increase the ratio if you want to dissolve more edges):

[image]

- Go into *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops* in order to extend the selection:

[image]

- Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*, or shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That helped, ALOT, tris is now ~8.5k, Thank you.